# formatting data from a cmd command

Tags: java, windows, cmd, hashmap

i need to run a CMD command to pull info from a device. i will get a stream of data after running the command. the structure of received data is as follows

```
date(mm-dd) time(hh:mm:ss.SS) int int String String: String
```

i want to write a java program to run the CMD command ( i`ve got this part covered) and preferably put each part of the received data in a variable and and in a hash map. then i want to check the last string (after ":")  and preform my command on it depending on the result.

my problem is i want my app to wait for input from the CMD (since it might run for few hours and between each result there may be a few hour delay ) and  dividing the results to strings and putting them in hash map ( or any other array- not important) . any idea how fix this ?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @IInspectable sorry. last paragraph i don't know how to perform that

Comment: We have no idea, what issue you are having. There is no code in your question, so it's unlikely that anyone could help you fix it. Please see [ask] to understand, what a good question looks like.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks.i will update my question with some of my codes.

Comment: @IInspectable i created another post with more info . check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768151/receiving-data-from-adb-and-formatting-the-input-stream-in-application)